# For general metric space, is it true that if all real valued function is bounded, then subset is compact?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

[image]

This theorem is stated for only subsets of Rn. I was wondering if this theorem is true for subsets of general metric space. And what about general topological spaces?

Comment: For the second question, this is a topological property known as pseudocompactness.

Comment: Yes, true for all metric spaces, not for all topological spaces. A space with this property is in general called *pseudocompact* and there are locally compact Hausdorff pseudocompact but non-compact spaces.